# Compile and pass array - AngularJS & PHP

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, angularjs

Trying to do CRUD with AngularJS and PHP.

**This is my current angular function;**

```
$scope.initCart = function () {
$http({
    method: 'post',
    url: url,
    data: $.param({ 'restID' : $scope.restID , 'type' : 'get_cart' }),
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
}).
    success (function(data, status, headers, config){
        if(data.success && !angular.isUndefined(data.data) ){
            $scope.cart = data.data;
        }else {
            $scope.cart = [];
        }
 }).
    error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
      //$scope.messageFailure(data.message);
   });
}
```

The function should post restID to PHP, get data from PHP based on logic and add to `$scope.cart` which should be an array containing all items that I can access using `ng-repeat`

**And my PHP is;**

```
function getCart ($connection) {
$data = array();
$rest_id = $_POST['restID'];

try {
    if(isset($_COOKIE['basket'])) {
        $cookie_id = $_COOKIE['basket'];
        $query = "SELECT * FROM cart WHERE cookie_id = $cookie_id";
        $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
        $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);

        if($count > 0) {
            $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

            $cart_id = $row['id'];
            $cart_total = $row['total'];
            $cart_subtotal = $row['subtotal'];

            $query = "SELECT * FROM cart_items WHERE cart_id = $cart_id";
            $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
            while($nrow = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                $data['data'][] = $nrow;
            }
            $data['success'] = true;
            echo json_encode($data);
            exit;
        }
    } else {
        setcookie('basket', session_id(), time()+604800, "/");
        $cookie = $_COOKIE['basket'];
        $cookie_id = session_id();
        $timestamp = date("H:i:s");

        // Insert cart into DB
        $query = "INSERT INTO `cart`(`cookie_id`, `restaurant_id`, `timestamp`) VALUES ('$cookie_id', '$rest_id', '$timestamp')";
        $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
        if ($result) {
            $data['success'] = false;
            echo json_encode($data);
            exit;
        }
    }
} catch (Exception $e) {
    $data = array();
    $data['success'] = false;
    $data['message'] = $e->getMessage();
    echo json_encode($data);
    exit;
   }
}
```

This is what I currently have; Can someone explain to me if this line is correct;

```
while($nrow = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
   $data['data'][] = $nrow;
}
```

I'm returning items from my DB using the `while`.
What I'm returning looks like this;

```
item1.name, item1.price, item1.qty, item1.id
item2.name, item2.price, item2.qty, item2.id
```

My goal is to get all these items, add them to `$scope.cart` and use `ng-repeat` to display them. I'm not very good with arrays.
I don't get any data in `$scope.cart`
I'm I data to it wrongly?

Comment: Do you get data back in data variable?

Comment: Please explain your specific problem - what reulst where you expecting? What did you get instead? Are there any errors thrown>

Comment: I'm not getting any data in `$scope.cart`

Comment: Does your request get fail or passes? Do you see anything console?

Comment: Passes because `$scope.cart` comes back empty. I use `ng-inspector` to check

Comment: Try running the same page in your terminal or browser and see the output. Use the `GET` server variable for that. Something like pathtoyourpage.php?restID=whatever

Comment: What is the difference between `$data['data'][] = $nrow;` and `$data['data'] = $nrow;`

Comment: Put a breakpoint in your initCart routine. It is possible that when you call initcart(), then $scope is not part of the closure when it executes (or at least not the right $scope object). I vague remember something to do with 'isolate'.

Comment: Please note that you PHP code is vulnerable to SQL injection! You need to sanitize the input such as `$_GET` and `$_POST` variables with the `mysqli_real_escape_string` function or for example `int_val` in case of numbers.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're making things way more complicated than they need to be. Less is always more.

Firstly, why not console log `data` to see if any information actually resides in there:

```
$http({
    url: url,
    method: 'post',
    data: $.param({restID: $scope.restID , type: 'get_cart'}),
    headers: {Content-Type: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
})
.success(function(data, status, headers, config)
{
    console.log('success', data);

    // now we know what we're working with...
})
.error(function(data, status, headers, config)
{
    console.log('failure', data);

    // welp, we probably cocked up our php script...
});
```

Secondly, you're giving yourself a ball-ache with repetitive code in your php. Why not render the json response in a singular line and make that the last thing you do, eg:

```
/**
 * Echo cart data given the connection.
 *
 * @param object $connection
 * @param array $data
 * @return void
 */
function get_cart($connection, $data = [])
{
    try
    {
        if (isset($_COOKIE['basket']))
        {
            // manipulate data array.
        }
        else
        {
            // manipulate data array.
        }
    }
    catch (Exception $e)
    {
        // manipulate data array.
    }

    echo json_encode($data);
}
```

You'll have a lot more control over your problem solving if you keep things refined. Hope this guides you in the right direction.